# xmpp openfire is not authenticating the php script I am using later for strophe attach

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to get SASL authetication for xmpp openfire server. after i run php script in curl. I do get the success packet from server as soon as passing the hash value.
but as i move forward bind the auth server gives me unauthorized error
i took some hint from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/strophe/Y2n2dQ5oSoU
see output logs below:

```
<body rid='16465' xmlns='http://jabber.org/ protocol/httpbind' to='iamnew.test' zml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='application/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>

<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" from="iamnew.test" authid="102b0b8b" sid="102b0b8b" secure="true" requests="2" inactivity="30" polling="5" wait="60" hold="1" ack="16465" maxpause="300" ver="1.6"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>JIVE-SHAREDSECRET</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features></body>

<body rid='16466' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='102b0b8b'><auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>dGVzdDJAbGV0c3RhbGsudGVzdAB0ZXN0MgB0ZXN0Mg== </auth></body>

<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/></body>
```

and here is when i move next for bind i get error 401 not authorized

```
<body rid='16467' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='102b0b8b'><iq type='set' id='_bind_auth_2' xmlns='jabber:client'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp- bind'/></iq></body>

<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="_bind_auth_2" to="letstalk.test/102b0b8b"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-  bind"/><error code="401" type="auth"><not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq></body>

<body rid='16468' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='102b0b8b'><iq  type='set'id='_session_auth_2' xmlns='jabber:client'><sessionxmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></iq></body><body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="_session_auth_2" to="letstalk.test/102b0b8b"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/><error code="401" type="auth"><not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq></body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [XMPP over BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) specification:

> Upon receiving the <success/> element, the client MUST then ask the
>   connection manager to restart the stream by sending a "restart
>   request"

so your next packet should look like this:

```
<body rid='1573741824'
      sid='SomeSID'
      to='example.com'
      xml:lang='en'
      xmpp:restart='true'
      xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
      xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```